# Not getting textarea'a value on form post

Tags: php, textarea

Here is a code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['flag'])) {
    echo "in";
$val=htmlspecialchars($_POST['area']);
echo $val;
if($val == "")
{
    $abstractErrorMsg="Please enter the abstract of your article";
    echo $abstractErrorMsg;
} 
}
?>
<html>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <input type="hidden" name="flag" value="hidden">
        Abstract*
        <textarea name="area" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;">

        </textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="btn">
    </form>
</html>
```

When I'm submitting the form without filling textarea, then also it is not displaying error message.

Can anyone figure what is causing this strange behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To check if textarea is empty or not use use this :

```
if (!strlen(trim($_POST['textarea'])))
```

Answer (score 2):

The default value of the textarea consists of a number of spaces and new lines. This is not equivalent to `""`.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your textarea to:

```
<textarea name="area" style="width: 300px; height: 100px;"></textarea>
```

Then it would be empty. At the moment there is some spaces and newlines in there.